# How to compile Blender from source on OSX?

Tags: installation, osx, versions

As it says on the can, How to compile Blender from source on OSX?

Jens Werwiebe from #blendercoders on the IRC channel kindly took me through the process, so I will post it up while it is still fresh in my memory.

Comment: For OpenMP you might have a look at my [instructions](http://bwide.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/build-blender-with-openmp-on-osx-10-9/).

Comment: Remember, questions about building or compiling anything from source involving other tools such as git and compilers are off-topic. These have been addressed elsewhere specifically the wiki and there is no one set way to go about it, each method has its own set of problems that can arise.

Comment: I realise this is closed as off-topic, but for anyone else who comes here: I was able to build blender from source using CLion (ie cmake 3.6) and Xcode 8.1 (`Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)`).

Answer (score 3):

The Blender documentation page https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Mac contains instructions on how you can compile Blender for a Mac machine. **Note** that the instructions below **might not be as accurate** anymore since lots of things might have changed.

---

But they don't quite work. When you get to the line "make", make fails, because the CLANG compiler that comes with XCode can't process "openMP" library.

Instead you need to use a specially built version of CLANG that DOES support openMP. (openMP pertains to threading on multiprocessor architectures, if you're curious. It is bad of Apple that their CLANG compilers behind with this.)

As you can see from that page, you pull the blender source code from git, and a bunch of already compiled binaries from SVN.

```
piBookAir:darwin-9.x.universal pi$ pwd
/Users/pi/Dev/Blender/blender-build/lib/darwin-9.x.universal

piBookAir:darwin-9.x.universal pi$ ls
README      freetype    opencollada osl     sdl
boost       gettext     opencolorio png     sndfile
clang-omp   jpeg        openexr     python      tiff
ffmpeg      llvm        openimageio release
fftw3       openal      openmp      samplerate
```

As you can see from the listing, it contains this special clang-omp

So you could probably make sure that that is getting found in your path before the existing CLANG, and it will work.

I haven't tried, because Jens showed me how to get it working using SCons.

SCons and CMake are two different ways of automating the process of setting up the build. if you're familiar with AutoTools, you can think of CMake as being AutoTools brought up to date in a way that works nicely on Windows systems also. And SCons does the same thing but using Python.

Now the big difference is that CMake is an actual program you have to download and install on your system, whereas SCons is just a Python script.

To me that makes SCons a clear winner, and it is indeed painless to do it this way.

So, create /pathto/blender-build/blender/user-config.py as follows:

```
CC = '../lib/darwin-9.x.universal/clang-omp/bin/clang'
CXX = '../lib/darwin-9.x.universal/clang-omp/bin/clang++'
```

And then run:

```
sysctl hw.logicalcpu
```

to find out how many CPUs new machine has (my MacBook Air has 4, a modern MacBook Pro has 12)

Now:

```
cd /pathto/blender-build/blender
python scons/scons.py -j4
```

And grab a cup of tea (or 4 if you forgot the -j4 parameter)

Now you should have:

```
/pathto/blender-build/install/darwin/blender.app
```

Comment: FWIW this is unnecessary with Xcode 8.1 (`Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)`). I just opened the project in CLion and hit build, worked fine. I expect command-line cmake would also work fine.